# Find the name of Directory Service User via Login Script in Perl

Tags: perl, macos, scripting, shell

I made a login script in Perl which has to run on Mac OS X clients and record the Logged in Directory Service user name.

I tried using `getlogin()` , `getpwuid($<)` respectively.

Now the problem is that since the login script runs as root on the system when the client logs in, `getpwuid($<)` always gives me the username as root. When using the `getlogin()` function, i do get the user name but for the user who logged in previously on the system.

I am using an open directory environment consisting of a Mac OS server.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about a [loginhook](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2420) script?  If so, it'll get passed the username as an argument, so `$ARGV[0]` should be what you need.

Comment: Hi, yes its a loginhook script. But the thing is the script does not reside on the Client machines. Its on the server, selected under the WorkGroup Manager. How can i pass $ARGV[0] from there?

Comment: The script is defined on the server, but actually executes on the client.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That is my exact setup. In the Workgroup Manager, under the Computer Group Preferences, i have selected my Login script. Do i have to pass anything from there? if yes, how

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `last`? [(man page)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/last.1.html) The log-in names and the duration are already in the `wtmp` file. I don't think you need to log them yourself.

Comment: Hi. Last and getlogin() both give the Last user who logged in. This is a Loginhook script